# How to get nth to the last element on ProtractorJS

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

This is what I have:

```
<input type=text class='someclass'> box1 </input>
<input type=text class='someclass'> box2 </input>
<input type=text class='someclass'> box3 </input>
```

I want to `getAttribute('value')` of text box2 using the `last()` function in ProtractorJS (meaning nth to the last element).

```
describe('get input box value',function(){
    it('get value', function(){
       expect(element.all(by.className('someclass')).last().getAttribute('value').toBe('box2'));
    });
});
```

I can't use the `get()` function like `get(1).getAttribute('value')` since my requirement is specific and this does not work for me.

Does anyone know anyway of getting the nth to the last element in ProtractorJS?

Comment: Could you use `by.css('.someclass:nth-last-child(2)')`?

Answer (score 9):

`get` should be all you need. It can take a negative index -n that represents nth elements counting from the last. See http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get

i.e. say you have 10 elements: ['a', 'b', ..., 'i', 'j']

```
$$('abc').get(0) -> 'a'
$$('abc').get(1) -> 'b'
$$('abc').get(-1) -> 'j'
$$('abc').get(-2) -> 'i'
$$('abc').get(-10) -> 'a'
```

Comment: Negative index! That's just awesome, missed that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`count()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count), but you would need to resolve it with `then` to get an actual count value:

```
var n = 1;  // set nth from the last

var elements = element.all(by.className('someclass'));
var index = elements.count().then(function (count) {
    expect(elements.get(count - n).getAttribute('value')).toBe('box2'));
});
```

As an alternative you can use `XPath`'s [`last()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/last) function:

```
var elm = element(by.xpath('//input[@class="someclass"][last() - 1]'));
expect(elm.getAttribute('value')).toBe('box2'));
```

Or, as Austin suggested in comments, a similar `CSS selector` based on [`nth-last-child()`](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/pseudoclass-nthlastchild/):

```
var elm = element(by.css('input.someclass:nth-last-child(2)'));
expect(elm.getAttribute('value')).toBe('box2'));
```